# gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi package not found on 10.04 LTS (Lucid)

Tags: apt, repository, gcc, arm

I am trying to install the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi package, but this is the error I am getting:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

I tried a couple of other packages like apt-cross and they got installed easily, but this package is not found. Based on info [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/03/28/installing-linaro-arm-cross-toolchain-on-ubuntu/) this package should be available in Lucid. Any thoughts on this?

edit: `sudo apt-get update` did not help. 
Ubuntu 10.04, 64-bit machine

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an error in this article. According to the [Ubuntu website](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi), `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` is only available in the universe repository since maverick (10.10) (search for the package name on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or visit the URL http://packages.ubuntu.com/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi).

On lucid, you can install the Linaro packages from the [Linaro Toolchain backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linaro-maintainers/+archive/toolchain), as described in the second part of the article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if download the maverick-compatible package, am I able to install it manually using dpkg?

Comment: @aminfar You might, but there's a good chance that it won't have the required dependencies. The package in the PPA should install seamlessly.